# Intersections of Circles: Dependent Poisson Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Distribute $N$ points randomly inside a square.

Take two circles that intersect:

...........................................
[image: from wolfram mathworld!]

Given that both circles lie entirely within the square, and that $P_1(n_r=k_1)$ gives the probability that there are $k_1$ points within the red circle, and $P_2(n_b=k_2)$ gives the probability that there are $k_2$ points within the blue circle, considering the sum of the magnitudes of the two sets of points $\sigma=n_r+n_b$, what is the probability $S(\sigma=n)$?

Assume $R=r=1$.

Note that if the circles didn't intersect, then $P_1$ and $P_2$ would both be independent Poisson distributions of intensity $\pi$.

Comment: I think I've got it, hang on...

Comment: If $R=R_1=r=R_2=1$ how come that these circles are entirely within the unit square?

Comment: (edit) Consider the square big enough to contain the circles